# Keyboard shortcut works only in 1 language (from 2)

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, language

I'm trying to understand why, for example, **Select All** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) works only when I'm in "Hebrew" and not working when on "ABC"?
This happens just when I'm on "input" in a browser, e.g.: Google search input or Slack message typing area.

macOS Monterey (12.4)

[image: Demo]

[image]

Comment: Does it work if you revert it to its default, Cmd/A?

Comment: n0pe :(, still the same